# Can't seem to calculate correct values

Tags: c++

Hello everyone I am learning functions so I took a old practice program and modified it to use functions. My problem is however when it comes time to display the commission I am calculating I am getting the wrong values. Any help would be appreciated. I have everything working except the commission prices.

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int ID;
double salary, pcs, printer, accessory, maint;
double pcbase = 8000.00, printerbase = 1500.00, accbase = 1000.00, maintbase = 500.00;
double pccomm = .15, printercomm = .10,acccomm = .05, maintcomm = .08;

double calcComm(double sales, double base, double percent);
void display(double, double, double, double);


int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter Salesman ID\n";
    cin>>ID;
    while (ID != -999)
    {
        cout<<"Enter base salary\n";
        cin>>salary;
        cout<<"Enter PC sales\n";
        cin>>pcs;
        pccomm = calcComm(pcs, pcbase, pccomm);

        cout<<"Enter Printer Sales\n";
        cin>>printer;
        printercomm = calcComm(printer, printerbase, printercomm);

        cout<<"Enter Accessory Sales\n";
        cin>>accessory;
        acccomm = (accessory, accbase, acccomm);

        cout<<"Enter Maintenance Sales\n";
        cin>>maint;
        maintcomm = (maint, maintbase, maintcomm);

        display(pccomm, printercomm, acccomm, maintcomm);
        cout<<"\n\nEnter Salesman ID or -999 to quit\n";
        cin>>ID;
    }

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

double calcComm(double sales, double base, double percent)
{
    double commission;
    if (sales < base)
        commission = 0;
    else 
        commission = sales * percent;
    return commission;
}

void display(double pccomm, double printercomm, double acccomm, double maintcomm)
{
    cout<<"Salesman ID:"<<ID;
    cout<<"\nProduct"<<"            Sales Amount"<<"      Commission\n";
    cout<<"Personal Computers"<<"     "<<pcs<<"               "<<pccomm;
    cout<<"\nPrinters"<<"               "<<printer<<"               "<<printercomm;
    cout<<"\nAccessories"<<"            "<<accessory<<"               "<<acccomm;
    cout<<"\nMaintenance"<<"            "<<maint<<"               "<<maintcomm;

    double total = 0,totaldue = 0;
    total = pccomm+printercomm+acccomm+maintcomm;
    totaldue = total+salary;
    cout<<"\n\n\nTotal Commission                               "<<total;
    cout<<"\n       Base Pay                                "<<salary;
    cout<<"\n      Total Due                                "<<totaldue;
}
```

My Desired Output is

```
Salesman ID: 111
Product                   Sales             Commission
Personal Computer         5000.00                0.00
Printers                  2000.00               50.00
Accessories                600.00                0.00
Mainteance                1000.00               40.00

Total Commission                                90.00
Base Pay                                      1234.56
Total Due                                     1324.56
```

Comment: -1 What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? What is the desired algorithm?

Comment: Sorry, the input is specific sales amounts for each product; PC sales, Printer sales, Accessory Sales, and Maintenance sales.    To recieve commission on any item it must be within a specific range (PC sales >8000.00, etc) The output is in the display function outputting all the info gathered and commission calculated in the calcComm function.

Comment: No. We need numbers. Input and output, expected and actual. And a formula. Not the one written in the code because we know that the compiler and the computer are fine.

Comment: Better. What is the actual output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
acccomm = (accessory, accbase, acccomm);
```

I assume this needs to be `acccomm = calcComm(accessory, accbase, acccomm);`.

Same for calculation of `maintcomm`. The way you wrote the code, it will use the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which just evaluates to the last operand.

Comment: This was my problem thanks for catching something I didn't :p

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess, since you didn't include any sample input or output. It would be unusual to pay no commission until the base was reached but pay comission calculated on the entire sales figures if the base was reached.

Did you mean

```
commission = (sales-base) * percent;
```

rather than

```
commission = sales * percent;
```

Answer (score 0):

commission = sales * base * percent?

You need to explain what the "base" variable is? is it unit price? Amount before commission? I assume sales is the number of units and percent is obvious.